# Converting an HTML File to PDF using iText in asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, itext

Am trying to convert an html file to pdf. Am using iText to create the pdf. My challenge now is:

1. Be able to save the generated pdf file to a folder
2. After the pdf has been generated it will prompt the download or save dialog box to the user, but the issue is that when the user click save, it will not save a pdf file. It will save an ordinary file,

Please i need your help to correct this, thank you.
Below is my code.

```
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr))
    {

        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("select Request_Id from Request where CONVERT(DATE, Date_Created) >= @start and CONVERT(DATE, Date_Created) <= @end ORDER BY Request_Id DESC;", conn);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@start", start);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@end", end);
        command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
        SqlDataReader sdr = command.ExecuteReader();

        //FileStream fs = new FileStream("Chapter1_Example1.pdf", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None);
        //MemoryStream fs = new MemoryStream();
        //Rectangle rec = new Rectangle(PageSize.A4);
        //Document doc = new Document(rec);
        //PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, fs);


        System.IO.StreamReader reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("Layout/header.html"));
        htmlStr += reader.ReadToEnd();


        if (sdr.Read())
        {
            while (sdr.Read())
            {
                //string date = sdr["Date_Created"].ToString();
                ///var status = Convert.ToInt32(sdr["Status"].ToString()) == 1 ? "Approved" : "Awaiting Approval";
                //htmlStr += "<td>" + sdr["Equipment_Type"].ToString() + "</td><td>" + sdr["Fault"].ToString() + "</td><td>" + sdr["Owner"].ToString() + "</td><td>" + sdr["Branch"].ToString() + "</td><td>" + getStatus((int)sdr["Request_Id"]) + "</td><td>" + DateTime.Parse(date).ToShortDateString() + "</td><td>" + DateTime.Parse(date).ToShortTimeString() + "</td><td><a href='Log-Details.aspx?Request-Id=" + sdr["Request_Id"].ToString() + "'>View Details</a></td></tr>";
                htmlStr += htmlString(sdr["Request_Id"].ToString());
            }

            System.IO.StreamReader reader2 = new System.IO.StreamReader(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("Layout/footer.html"));
            htmlStr += reader.ReadToEnd();
            htmlStr += htmlStr.Replace("{date_year}", DateTime.Now.Year.ToString());

            MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();
            TextReader xmlString = new StringReader(htmlStr);

            Document doc = new Document();


            PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, memStream);
            //document.SetPageSize(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.A4);
            doc.Open();
            byte[] byteArray = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(htmlStr);
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(byteArray);
            XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(writer, doc, ms, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);

            doc.Close();

            Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString() + ".pdf");
            Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
            Response.BinaryWrite(memStream.ToArray());
            Response.End();
            Response.Flush();

            conn.Close();
            conn.Dispose();
        }

        conn.Close();
        conn.Dispose();

        //doc.Add(new Paragraph(string.Format(htmlStr)));

        //doc.Close();
        //writer.Close();
        //fs.Close();
        //Response.ContentType = "pdf/application";
        //Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename="+ DateTime.Now + ".pdf");
        //Response.OutputStream.Write(fs.GetBuffer(), 0, fs.GetBuffer().Length);

    }
```

Comment: What is your question ?  "Help me" is not a question; everyone wants help here.

Comment: Try setting content length header to `memStream.Length`